# Can't access Xamarin CustomPin's attributes

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

Im using Xamarin.Forms.Maps to create Pins on a Map.

This is the Custom Pin im trying to use.

```
public class CustomPin : Pin
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Url { get; set; }
    }
```

after I add one of my custom pins to my map this function gets called automatically on the CustomMapRenderer inside the android project. which lets me set things about the pin(which is called Marker in android for some reason).

```
protected override MarkerOptions CreateMarker(Pin pin)
        {
            var marker = new MarkerOptions();
            marker.SetPosition(new LatLng(pin.Position.Latitude, pin.Position.Longitude));
            marker.SetTitle(pin.Label);
            marker.SetSnippet(pin.Address);
            marker.SetIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.FromAsset("imagenBITMAP.bmp"));

            return marker;
        }
```

the problem is... I'm trying to access the `(Pin pin)` with something like this
`var testVar = pin.Name;` to choose a different `marker.SetIcon` image depending on the name that the pin has. but `pin.` doesnt bring up the attributes of the CustomPin.

This is what pin shows when debuggin step by step:

[image: Text]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to cast it to the correct type first

```
var custom = (CustomPin)pin;

if (custom.Name == "...")
```

Comment: cant believe it was as easy as that, thank you Jason.